# How to call Struts 2 action with a parameter in each jQuery DataTable row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, struts2

I work in JAVAEE project with Struts 2 and I am using jQuery DataTable where I want to add a link with each row to call an action with `id`.

This is the HTML code:

```xml
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div id="dataTables-example_wrapper"
        class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline" role="grid">
        
        <table
            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer"
            id="matable"
            aria-describedby="dataTables-example_info">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Libellé planing</th>
                    <th>Nom de la classe</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>


        </table>

        
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I push data from with AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(
            
    function() {
        // recuperation des ressources
        $.ajax({
            url : "listPlaning",
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            mimeType : 'application/json',

            success : function(msg) {
                for ( var i in msg) {
                    
                    $("#matable").dataTable()
                            .fnAddData(
                                    [ 
                                      msg[i].libellePlanning,
                                      msg[i].classe,
//this code doesn't work                  "<s:url var='test' action='action'><s:param name='id'>"+msg[i].idPlaning+"</s:param></s:url>"                                         
                                      ]);
                    
                }
                
                
            },
            error : function(error) {

            },
            complete : function(x) {

            }
        });
    });
```

I don't know how to call action with `<a href="">` and I tried to put Struts 2 tags but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try relative URL

```
'test.action?id='+msg[i].idPlaning
```

Comment: like this <a href="myaction.action?id=idPlaning"> link</a>

Comment: I thought it was necessary to pass by struts2 tag thank you